# Updating Dynamic Data on a GatsbyJS Site

Tags: gatsby

I am creating a Gatsby site that needs to make a dynamic, fetch api call.  However, the particular api call in question does not allow client-side api calls -- only server side.  So I need to make the call in a node environment using `node-fetch`.

What's more - I need to run this fetch api call on a regular interval (e.g., every 5 minutes).

Is this possible with Gatsby?  If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby is just an opinionated React configuration as far as your front-end is concerned. It sounds like you might approach this by running a small server with a crontab that executes a simple JS script every 5 minutes that fetches content from another API and writes that data out as a static JSON file. Then in your Gatsby app you can simply fetch and parse that static JSON file [onClientEntry](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onClientEntry), and set a timer to refresh it periodically.

This approach removes the need to run a nodejs server entirely, which also obviates the need for a process monitor and other such devops tooling.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  I'm going to give it a try -- thanks.

Comment: P.S.  Is it perhaps possible to do this via a gatsby-source-plugin?  I ask, because I already created such a plugin to pull in the data.  If so, would you mind letting me know how on this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398710/updating-data-in-gatsby-source-plugin.  Thanks.